# Using external styles and multiple class names with webpack css loader

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

Is there a way to use external css (i.e bootstrap, semantic-ui, foundation, etc) while still getting the base64 class names? This could be possible if there was a way to use multiple class names.

Currently you can only use one class name like this

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import style from './App.scss';
import styles from '../semantic/dist/components/button.min.css'

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className={style.button}>Hello Webpack!!!</div>
    );
  }
}
```

I need to be able to use multiple class names like this:

```
<div className={style.btn} + {style.red}>Hello Webpack!!!</div>
```

in order to use css frameworks and get the base64 class names. Is there a way to do this?

#### TL;DR: I want to have multiple class names from a file that doesn't have :local(...) for each of the class names (semantic-ui) and get the base64 random class names. Using them. If I import `../semantic/dist/components/button.min.css` I can use `className="ui red button"` fine, but if I `import Semantic from '../semantic/dist/components/button.min.css'`, I can't use `className={Semantic.ui + " " + Semantic.button}`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. `className` accepts a string, so you can easily use multiple values: `className={\`${class1} ${class2}\`}`. But I'm not sure what you mean when you refer to the "base64 class names" of the frameworks. Why wouldn't you use classes like normal?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller I want to have multiple class names from a file that doesn't have `:local(...)` for each of the class names (semantic-ui) and get the base64 random class names.

Comment: Right, but what's the problem? Are you having trouble importing them or using them?

Comment: Using them. If I import `../semantic/dist/components/button.min.css` I can use `className="ui red button"` fine, but if I `import Semantic from '../semantic/dist/components/button.min.css'`, I can't use `className={Semantic.ui + " " + Semantic.button}` most likely because the `semantic-ui` css files don't have the `:local(...)` prefix.

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused. If they don't use `:local`, why would they have random class names? Back to my original comment, why can't you do `className="ui red button"`?

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller My client wants the class names to be random.

Comment: The random class names are only generated for `:local` classes. Otherwise, there's no need for them and would either (a) break the ordinary use case of classes, or (b) double the size of the resulting css file. So unless I'm missing something major, the loaders don't support what you're doing - mostly because I honestly can't imagine a legitimate use case for doing it. But if you can't talk your client down, you may have to resort to `grep` and `sed` and do it yourself.

Comment: @JoshDavidMiller Yeah. I have exchanged multiple emails with him about this, and it looks like i'm gonna be have to just manually add `:local` and add a grunt task for that for when I rebuild `semantic-ui` ;(

Comment: Unless there is a way to default classes with no prefix as `:local`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use classnames npm module

```
import classNames from 'classnames'

render: <div className={classNames(style.red,style.btn)}>Hello Webpack!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See this for using bootstrap along with your css styles.. [Webpack Multiple CSS Loaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36798813/webpack-multiple-css-loaders?rq=1)

And to use multiple classnames you can simply write like this in place of

```
{style1} + {style2}: 
   className={
       styles.button + " " + styles.red
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

or: className={ [styles.button, styles.red].join(' ') }

Comment: This is basically the same answer as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38222204/7404943) just concatenates strings in other way

Comment: Yes, I know .  So one can choose which one works the best :-)

Comment: There are also other ways to concatenate string but it's not subject of this question