# Webpack Multiple CSS Loaders

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load bootstrap CSS to make it available to webpack to use within the application.  However, I also have a CSS loader with localIndentName for component specific CSS to avoid naming conflicts within other components.  Because of this, bootstrap classnames are getting renamed to things like...node_modules__blah__blah, etc.

What would be the easiest way to avoid this?  I know adding the CDN to the header would be quick, but the browser seems to timeout the CDN lookup after so many hot reloads, not sure if the CDN is throttling or what (if there's a way to fix this, that'd be the best solution, in my opinion).

Configuration:

```
{ 
  test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
  loaders: [
    'style?sourceMap',
    'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
    'resolve-url',
    'sass?sourceMap',
  ],
}
```

Thanks!

Thanks to the guidance, here's the configuration I ended up with:

```
  {
    test: /(\.css|\.scss)$/,
    loaders: [
      'style?sourceMap',
      'css?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
      'resolve-url',
      'sass?sourceMap',
    ],
    exclude: [
      path.resolve('node_modules', 'bootstrap-sass')
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
    include: [
      path.resolve('node_modules', 'bootstrap-sass')
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You can add second loader for bootstrap css files with correct `localIdentName`. Fitst loader will ignore bootstrap by adding [exclude](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders) (`exclude: 'bootstrap'`) parameter and second will parse only bootstrap by adding _include_ (`include: 'bootstrap'`).

Comment: Thanks for the input! Will give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach would be to use Bootstrap's Less or Sass sources. Alternatively, you can use the `{include, exclude}` option and provide a separate loader configuration for styles installed from the registry.

Comment: Excellent, will try these approaches when I'm back at my desk!